# Logic Explanation for Exists in SQL

Tags: mysql

So I have orders and neworders table like below

```
**neworders**
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
| orderId | customerid | ordertotal | discountrate | orderdate  |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
|       1 |          3 |    1910.64 |         5.49 | 2019-12-03 |
|       2 |          4 |     150.89 |        15.33 | 2019-06-11 |
|       3 |          5 |     912.55 |        13.74 | 2019-09-15 |
|       4 |          7 |     418.24 |        14.53 | 2019-05-28 |
|       5 |         55 |     512.55 |        13.74 | 2019-06-15 |
|       7 |         57 |     118.24 |        14.53 | 2019-12-28 |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.013 sec)
```

```
**orders**
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
| orderId | customerid | ordertotal | discountrate | orderdate  |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
|       1 |          3 |    1910.64 |         5.49 | 2019-12-03 |
|       2 |          4 |     150.89 |        15.33 | 2019-06-11 |
|       3 |          5 |     912.55 |        13.74 | 2019-09-15 |
|       4 |          7 |     418.24 |        14.53 | 2019-05-28 |
|       5 |         55 |     512.55 |        13.74 | 2019-06-15 |
|       6 |         57 |     118.24 |        14.53 | 2019-12-28 |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.056 sec)
```

I want to use exists with subqueries. Here's the syntax

```
select*from neworders where exists(select orderId from orders);
```

And here's the result

```
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
| orderId | customerid | ordertotal | discountrate | orderdate  |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
|       1 |          3 |    1910.64 |         5.49 | 2019-12-03 |
|       2 |          4 |     150.89 |        15.33 | 2019-06-11 |
|       3 |          5 |     912.55 |        13.74 | 2019-09-15 |
|       4 |          7 |     418.24 |        14.53 | 2019-05-28 |
|       5 |         55 |     512.55 |        13.74 | 2019-06-15 |
|       7 |         57 |     118.24 |        14.53 | 2019-12-28 |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

I'm so confused by the output or orderId which is 7, what is the logic in here?

Comment: The subquery is not correllated with the main query. So it's true as long as the `orders` table is not empty.

Comment: Your inner subquery has no filter, you might want to check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: Your logic says that if your sub-query returns at least 1 row, then your `WHERE` condition us `True`.  It should work with `IN` though not efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exists(select orderId from orders)` is true if the subquery returns any rows. Since there's no `WHERE` clause in the subquery, it will return all the rows in the `orders` table. So the `EXISTS` condition is true whenever the `orders`  table is not empty.

SInce that's true, the `WHERE` condition in the main query will be true for all rows of `neworders`.

If you only want the rows of `neworders` that are also in `orders`, you need to add a correlating condition to the subquery.

```
select *
from neworders AS n
where exists(
    select orderId 
    from orders AS o
    WHERE n.orderId = o.orderId
);
```

You can also just use a `JOIN`

```
SELECT n.*
FROM neworders AS n
JOIN orders AS o ON n.orderId = o.orderId
```